# Zonal statistics with feature collection column (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics, feature-collection

I have run into a very similar problem a few times while working in Google Earth Engine and never found a good solution.

I am working with raster data (continuous values) and a feature collection of ecosystems, and my goal is to summarize the raster values over a column within the feature collection. The ecosystems shapefile has a column that assigns each ecosystem to a biome (so there are 827 ecosystems and 14 biomes). I want to calculate the mean raster value over these biomes.

In ArcMap I would use zonal statistics as table and specify that I want to calculate the statistics over the biome column, but I have not found a good way to accomplish this in GEE. So far I have been using the reduceRegions function and specifying my feature collection as the collection, but this only lets me summarize the raster values over the 827 ecosystems.

Is there a function that would allow me to do this in GEE? Or would it be easier to just make the changes to the shapefile in Arc and then re-import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, but the most efficient will be to use a grouped reducer (there are detailed examples in the User's Guide at https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_grouping).

It would look something like this:

```
// Create a raster of biomes
var biomes = ee.Image().int().paint(ecosystems, "biome").rename("biomes")

// Aggregate pixels, grouping on the biome band (the first one).
var results = biomes.addBands(raster)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean().group(0), roi, scale)
```

If you don't already have a fixed roi, you can probably just take the bounds of the ecosystems:

```
var aoi = ecosystems.geometry().bounds()
```

Comment: That worked great! I didn't think to convert to raster first